How to let airflow(scheduler) dynamically load custom modules without restarting?
I use airflow to schedule my ETL jobs, and the project have version control.
Environment is built with airflow docker image, and the codes use bind mount.
So any changes (including git pull command) are synchronized with the container.
The file structure is like the follows:
airflow_home/
|-- dags/
|-- plugins/
|-- custom_module/
.
The current situation is that if the code is changed in dags/plugins, airflow scheduler will read the latest code.
However, if there is a code change in the custom module, airflow scheduler will not detect it.
It will still use the old module instead of reading the latest code.
I think it's because the custom module is already loaded into memory after airflow scheduler starts.
Is there any way to dynamically load a custom module into the airflow scheduler?
I've tried:

using PYTHONPATH to specify the module path
using the setup tool to create an editable package

Both methods failed, still can't get the latest code.
Is there any way to dynamically load the module when a DAG task is running?
(( Using importlib.reload is work, but it adds a lot of code to each .py file. So I don't plan to use this yet.

TLDR:
Set AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTE_TASKS_NEW_PYTHON_INTERPRETER to True
This setting has default of False.
It controls over should tasks be executed via forking of the parent process
False: Execute via forking of the parent process

True: Spawning a new python process, slower than fork, but means plugin changes picked up by tasks straight away

The full context:
Plugins in Airflow are lazy loaded. Thus if you want changes in plugins to take affect immediately you need either to restart the machine or to make them reloaded when you use them.

Plugins are by default lazily loaded and once loaded, they are never
reloaded (except the UI plugins are automatically loaded in
Webserver). To load them at the start of each Airflow process, set
[core] lazy_load_plugins = False in airflow.cfg.
This means that if you make any changes to plugins and you want the
webserver or scheduler to use that new code you will need to restart
those processes. However, it will not be reflected in new running
tasks after the scheduler boots.
By default, task execution uses forking. This avoids the slowdown
associated with creating a new Python interpreter and re-parsing all
of Airflow’s code and startup routines. This approach offers
significant benefits, especially for shorter tasks. This does mean
that if you use plugins in your tasks, and want them to update you
will either need to restart the worker (if using CeleryExecutor) or
scheduler (Local or Sequential executors). The other option is you can
accept the speed hit at start up set the
core.execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter config setting to True,
resulting in launching a whole new python interpreter for tasks.
(Modules only imported by DAG files on the other hand do not suffer
this problem, as DAG files are not loaded/parsed in any long-running
Airflow process.)

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/plugins.html#when-are-plugins-re-loaded


Package your modules - how to
Pip install them

you can pip install providing repo link (storing creds follows same rules as if you would be doing git clone X e.g. ssh) e.g. pip install https://github...
if your company uses in-house pypi e.g. jfrog upload your package there and pip install from it (you can make an infra solution mirroring public pypi, where artifactory knows whether to pull package from www or from internal pypi)




I've tried packaging module (via "pip install -e ." with setup.py to find my custom module).
I know that airflow scheduler will cache modules when it starts,  is there any detail that I haven't noticed?

Add it to docker image and rebuilt each time code changes. When python kernel runs it always will cache dependencies.
